# Автоматизация анализа траффика Москвы используя яндекс навигатор

Tags: android

Всем привет. Выбираю квартиру в Москве, хочу сравнить различные ЖК, учитывая транспортную обстановку г Москва.
Примерный вариант работы. 
Я выставляю 4 точки откуда надо ехать, и несколько точек куда. И ставлю время и день когда надо собирать информацию. Через месяц у меня наберётся статистика где из какого жк лучше добираться до моих точек. 
Кто то сталкивался с такой задачей? Или есть другие варианты решения задачи.